# Android: recognize with gestures two digit numbers

Tags: android, numbers, gestures

I have create an application using gestures library and works well when I try to detect numbers from 0 to 9, but now I want to detect from 0 to 99. The application is easy, only just ask for an aritmethic operation and the user must to draw the correct result in screen. How can I implement the two digit reconize ?

Comment: Apply timeout and wait for next gesture input, if it was within time then read gesture or just say timeout.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make gesture for two separate symbols unless make multi-touch. Which doesn't make much sense.

I think best approach would be to recognize individual digits. And then wait certain amount of time. After which you get other digit or interpret as single one